Extremal function definition problem while proving $ex(n, P_4) = n+1$.
I'm struggling to prove that $ex(n, P_4) = n+1$, this exercise was assigned to us during the class, where with $P_4$ i mean the path on $4$ vertices (indicated with $P^3$ in some books). I've set up the proof by induction as follows:
Assume a graph $G$ with $|V(G)| = n \geq 4$.
By induction on $n$, $|E(G)| = n+1 \Rightarrow \exists$ a cycle $C$ in $G$. Now, if $|C| \geq 4$ then $C$ has a subgraph $P_4$, and then $G$ has a subgraph $P_4$. Else, if $C$ is a triangle with $V(C) = \{x, y, z\}$, then
If the degree of one $v \in \{x, y, z\}$ is $\geq 3$, then we get a $P_4$ in $C$, and so $P_4$ in $G$.
Else, $G - \{x, y, z\}$ has $n-3$ vertices and at least $n+1-3$ edges. So, by induction, $G - \{x, y, z\}$ has $P_4$ as a subgraph $\Rightarrow$ $G$ has $P_4$ as a subgraph.
Thus if $G$ contains a triangle, the claim holds. Now, assume claim false and take $G$ to be a counterexample with minimal vertex set, i.e. $G$ has at least $n+1$ edges and no $P_4$ as a subgraph. Note that $|V(G)| \geq 4$ because it has $n+1$ edges. But now there is at least a triangle in $G \Rightarrow$ the claim is verified.
My question is: Is it possible that the claim was $ex(n, P_4) = n$ instead of $ex(n, P_4) = n+1$? And, if yes, how should I continue/modify the proof?

I think $ex(n, P_4) = n$ is probably correct. As you have argued, the graph cannot have a $C_4$, but must contain a cycle, so it has a triangle, $T$. If there was a path from $T$ to $V(G) - T$, then we get a $P_4$, which means that $T$ is disjoint from $G$. We can use induction to conclude that the best we can do is a disjoint union of triangles, so $ex(n, P_4) = n, n-1$ depending if $3$ divides $n$ or not (when $3 \nmid n$ use the star graph).

Yes, I also think so. Thank you very much for the response!
